# Type hinting pandas dataframe with specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, type-hinting

Suppose I have the following function:

```
def foo(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    x = df["x"]
    y = df["y"]
    df["xy"] = x * y

    return df
```

Is there a way I could hint that my function is accepting a data frame that must have the "x" and "y" column and that it will return a data frame with the "x", "y" and "xy" columns, instead of just a general data frame?

Comment: You might be interested in [`pydantic`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/)

Comment: Why don't you do `def foo(df: pd.DataFrame, col1: str, col2: str)`?

Comment: @roganjosh I don't think creating a new type would help me here I still want to work with pandas, just want people to know that my DataFrame has those particular columns. But maybe I might be missing your point.

Comment: I don't think you've missed my point, actually. This is what we've started using at work, but then I realise that it is us that creates the df inside the library itself, but the interface doesn't directly validate the df in the API, only once it goes a bit deeper, and it seems a little harder to get it seamless with `pandas`

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't see how adding additional parameters would help me here, I just want to type hint, I don't want to modify the function behavior

Comment: IMHO, type hinting is strictly associated with the function signature and has nothing to do with how the function handles/generates local variables. If you're trying to make type-hinting understand internal/local variables, you're doing it wrong. What I actually meant was: `foo(df:DataFrame, col1:str, col2:str): x=df[col1]...`

Comment: @roganjosh I don't really need to validate, it's just a matter of ease to understand, I just wish there were something like a pd.DataFrame["x", "y"], it would make life a lot easier.

Comment: @QuangHoang I know, but by modifying the signature it already changes from a function that takes 1 argument to a function that takes 3 arguments, and I would have to modify already all the function calls in my codebase, that's what I meant, and besides, this still doesn't make it clear that my df has to have a column named "x". I want strictly to change the type, maybe through a NewType from typing or something similar

Comment: 1. Make your params optional with defaults so you don't need to change all your function calls. 2. Do an explicit check inside your function to ensure that `df` has those two columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so, I'm not sure if this is the correct way of implementing it, but seems to work for me. If you see any mistakes or alternatives let me know and I can edit the response but my solution was basically creating a new class and implementing the `__class_getitem__` method as seen in the [Pep 560](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0560/#class-getitem), this was my final code:

```
from typing import List
import pandas as pd


GenericAlias = type(List[str])

class MyDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    __class_getitem__ = classmethod(GenericAlias)


def foo(df: MyDataFrame[["x", "y"]]) -> MyDataFrame[["x", "y", "xy"]]:
    df["xy"] = df["x"] * df["y"]
    return df
```

---

## Edit

The [Pandera library](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) is a better alternative that I did not know about when I posted the question.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandera.typing import Series, DataFrame

class InputSchema(pa.DataFrameModel):
    x: Series[float]
    y: Series[float]

class ReturnSchema(pa.DataFrameModel):
    x: Series[float]
    y: Series[float]
    xy: Series[float]


def foo(df: DataFrame[InputSchema]) -> DataFrame[ReturnSchema]:
    x = df['x']
    y = df['y']
    df['xy'] = x * y

    return df
```