# Can VS Code suggest all dataframe column labels?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code, code-completion

Is there any way to make VS Code suggest all dataframe column labels?

[image: screenshot showing suggestions list]

From the above sample dataframe, I expect all the column labels (Country, Product, Price, Qty) is going to popup. But none show up after I select 'Country'.

Comment: I just edited the question and I realized you weren't using any of the exact terminology before. Hopefully this gives you some terms you can try researching :) I'd like to know too. "Intellisense" is another one.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed the Jupyter extension does suggest column names, but you have to start typing them first. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43890844/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/69728330/11107541

Comment: Related, maybe a duplicate: [Is there a way to get autocompletion for pandas dataframe columns in VSCode editor or interactive mode?](/q/69628815/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea I'd say this question is different because it's parsing a dataframe from a file _at runtime_ (I'm currently writing up an answer)

Comment: did you get suggestions for `'Country'`? Or did you type that all in manually?

Comment: I do get 'Country' (and other labels as well) as suggestion. But the suggestion only works one time when  none of the label is selected. After I selected one label, the suggestion (or popup) does not work anymore.

Comment: then your question is not correct. You get completion on the first tuple element of the data frame array index but on following tuple elements. maybe the type definition for `DataFrame[]` can be modified so VSC Jupyter suggests next column names

Comment: @user in your answer you suggest to write a VSC extension to do this, but are we able to write an extension that interacts with the Jupyter Webview (??), and that is able to do runtime Python introspection

Comment: @rioV8 I'm actually not sure. Good thing I deleted that answer I suppose.

Comment: @user13617491 If you start typing the other column names, do they appear in the suggestions?

Comment: @user The question I linked doesn't say anything about runtime... I mean, the answer does define a df at runtime, but it doesn't actually affect anything. Maybe you're confused with `text` suggestions? (`editor.suggest.showWords`) Those would have a little "abc" symbol instead of a wrench (though, I get a cube on mine, but then I'm using Jedi with Codium).

Comment: Oh wait a minute, does the dataframe have a MultiIndex? Cause if not, then to select multiple columns, you need to put a list, i.e. double up the brackets: `data[['Country','']]`. It'd help to provide a [mre]. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: Er, actually, I just tried doubling up the brackets myself and no column suggestions came up no matter what I tried... But I'm using Jedi (i.e. not Pylance) on Codium so YMMV. To be clear, if I put single brackets and start typing column names, they do get suggested.